# Zf2 pagination in categories (problems with routes)

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I am trying to create pagination in my news module.

First of all I have this modes:

1. All news feed
2. Feed by category

I need to create pagination for both modes. I had just created pagination for all news feed. There are no problems. I have route `news` + I added `pagination` route as child route:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'news' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/news',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'pagination' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/page-:page',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'page'      => 1,
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),
                // more child routes
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I am using paginationControls like this:

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(
    $this->news,
    'Sliding',
    'pagination_control',
    array('route' => 'news/pagination')
)?>
```

Pagination for all news feed is done.

Also, I need to add pagination for feed by category. I have problems there. I already had child route `category` in route `news`. I added child route `pagination` to `news/category`. Config become so:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'news' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/news',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'pagination' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/page-:page',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'page'      => 1,
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),
                'category' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/:category',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'category'     => '[a-z]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',
                            'action'     => 'category',
                        )
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'pagination' => array(
                            'type' => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/page-:page',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'category'     => '[a-z]+',
                                    'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'page'      => 1,
                                )
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Ok. Now I use paginationControl like this:

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(
    $this->news,
    'Sliding',
    'pagination_control',
    array('route' => 'news/category/pagination', array('category' => $this->category->getUrl()))
)?>
```

Now, when I try to access any page with pagination control, I get `Missing parameter "category"` error.

Probably, I understand why this error appears: I specify route `news/category/pagination` and specify parameter of THIS route `category`, but there is no parameter `category` in route `news/category/pagination`, there is such parameter in route `news/category`, but I didn't specified it – its wrong. Am I right in my assumption?

So, how I can make pagination works with categories?

Huge thanks!

Comment: Can you add the `pagination_control` view code? as a child of news/category ,  news/category/pagination need the `:category` parameter. You don't really need to create a different route for pagination

Comment: @Gabriel It is standart. I don't know where I can found this view :(. `as a child of news/category , news/category/pagination need the :category parameter` – thats the question: how to call route `news/category/pagination` and set parameter of parent route `news/category`? So you suggest to add parameter in route just and don't create new child route, as suggested in question?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to accomplish that is just merging the two routes into one.

```
           'category-page' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:category/page-:page',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'category'     => '[a-z]+',
                        'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',
                        'action'     => 'category',
                        'page'      => 1
                    )
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
```

Shall work.

You can also make "page" optional by:

```
'route' => '/:category[/page-:page]',
```

It's is the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you! I will use it, if it will not be possible to use my route structure. Thanks for the idea, but I use existing routes already :( Is there a way to achieve what I want without changing route config?

Comment: There isn't a full explanation on documentation of what's going wrong with your routes. My bet is that you can't use a segmented route as a child of another segmented route when the parent has a parameter. You can only accomplish a "Route->ChildRoute1->ChildRoute2" when Route and ChildRoute1 wasn't composed by parameter, like /register/edit/:id, never /register/:edit/:id